# Using SNMP to retrieve network information

Tags: c#, snmp

I need to create an application in c# where it able to retrieve network information from IP address. Can anyone give me some advise on how to retrieve network information using SNMP protocol?

Comment: Your question is very vague, but I do not think that SNMP is the answer. What is the problem you are trying to solve? More details are needed here....

Comment: @JamieMeyer I want to create an application, wherenever I insert the ip address,it able to retrieve the information in SNMP. such as the location, hostname n etc. Is it not possible to do that with snmp?Please =(

Comment: Unless there is an SNMP agent monitoring incoming requests at that IP, you won't get the things you want.

Comment: @LexLi yes,I already configure the SNMP agent at that IP. but now I just want to create an application that retrieve the IP information. Please.

Comment: Assume that you understand how to use an MIB explorer to communicate with the agent, simply record what the explorer sends and do the same in your C# code. That's all I can suggest.

Comment: @LexLi sorry,but Im new to this, can you guide me more on how to integrate the MIB explorer in order to communicate with the agent? and how to do the record? please.

Comment: Then it's a challenge you need to resolve offline by reading more about SNMP. Without a basic understanding of that protocol and its usage in mind, any further discussion online will only waste your time and others'. Can you start from Essential SNMP? http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/snmp/